# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: sql-server, authentication, connectivity

When attempting to log on to a SQL Server that lives on a different domain, I get the following error:

> The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

I am using Windows Credential Manager to enable Windows Authentication across domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that when setting up the credentials for the remote server in windows credential manager, I had not specified the domain alongside the username.

I had

```
sql.domain.name:1433
username
pwd
```

the correct version was:

```
sql.domain.name:1433
domain.name\username
pwd
```

So, specifying the fully qualified domain name in the username field of credential manager resolved the issue.